# Sharing a variable between multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have a class project to create html page(s) with javascript without using any server side communications, the first is about user input an specially numbers.
In the first page an instructor must enter information about his class an its students number,
and then when done, he clicks next and a new page opens asking for each student information and grades. But when changing from the first page to the second the variable of the students number becomes undefined.
I'm using this part

```
var  snum;

function savesnum(val){
snum =val;}
```

And also tried,

```
var snum;
function savesnum(){
snum = document.getElementById('stunb').value; }
```

Comment: Reopened. The other one asks about "using the query string" only, this one here does not care how to share the variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Answer (score 19):

Here is an example of using [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) to pass data between two html pages being served on the same domain. This will not work accross different domains because of the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

The example consists of two pages hosted on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) but you could just as easily serve these files from your local file system. Either way there is no server side communication involved in this example.

The first page allows the user to enter some text in a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/textarea) element. There is a save [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button) which when clicked will fire a [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) that executes the save handler (the [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) specified as the second attribute of addEventListener) that gets the user entered text and saves it in localStorage with the key `mySharedData`

[Page 1 on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/dfqsK/)

HTML

```
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<div>
    <button id="save">Save</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
/*jslint sub: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */

(function (global) {
    document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function () {
        global.localStorage.setItem("mySharedData", document.getElementById("output").value);
    }, false);
}(window));
```

The second page recalls the saved text from the key `mySharedData` that is in localStorage and displays it in the textarea

[Page 2 on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ayvPq/)

HTML

```
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Javascript

```
/*jslint sub: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */

(function (global) {
    document.getElementById("output").value = global.localStorage.getItem("mySharedData");
}(window));
```

Both examples are wrapped in an anonymous [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) which is executed immediately, and into which we pass the [window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) which we then reference as the variable named `global`.

Finally, the first line is a comment, but not any old comment; it is an instruction that is used by [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/); a static code analysis tool used in javascript software development for checking if JavaScript source code complies with [coding conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) set out by Douglas Crockford.

Alternatives would be to use:

[cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), once again the Same-origin policy would apply.

or

[URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) [query-strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) which would be part of the address used when taking you to the next page, where it can be read in Javascript to obtain data.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using cookies:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

> A cookie is a variable that is stored on the visitor's computer. Each time the same computer requests a page with a browser, it will send the cookie too. With JavaScript, you can both create and retrieve cookie values.

```
function savesnum(val) {
    document.cookie = 'snum:'+val; //Set the cookie
}

function getsnum() {
    var start = document.cookie.indexOf('snum:'); //Get the location of the cookie value
    var stop = document.cookie.indexOf(';'); //Get the end of the cookie value

    return document.cookie.substring(start+5, stop); //Return the value of the cookie (+5 because 'snum:' is 5 chars long)
}
```

Comment: How can i use the return of getsnum as a variable

Answer (score 0):

when you window open a new page or redirect to a new page, you are on a new window object, you are not able to get the "snum" which is defined on the first window object as a global variable.

in this case you can pass the snum as a "get" parameter alone with the url and get the parameter at the new window.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
var snum;
```

that just creates a Javascript variable.

It doesn't even add `snum` to the DOM (Document Object Model) of the same page. Which is what you're trying to do (although on a different page) with:

```
document.getElementById('stunb').value;
```

You can call `getElementById()` only to get a DOM node/element like a `<p id="mainText">` paragraph node. To pass around values from one page to the other you can use:

- Cookies
- URL parameters (like google.com/search?q=**parameter+value**)

There are other methods as well but they would require some server side code.

In your case you can pass the number of students as follows:

```
<form action="nextPage.html">
    Number of Students: <input type="text" name="snum" />
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

On `nextPage.html`

```
<script type="text/script">
<!--
    var snum = location.search.substr(location.search.indexOf("=")+1);
    alert(snum); // assumes snum will be sent as "nextPage.html?snum=10"
//-->
</script>
```