# how do i pass this bootstrap html form to next page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

i have a simple form with a gender drop down and a temperature dropdown and i want them to go to the next page and just simple be outputted to the screen.  I think i may have to change my save button as well. must use javascript with i could use php lol

```
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="sel1">Gender:</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="gender">
      <option>Male</option>
      <option>Female</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="sel1">Temperature (Degrees):</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="gender">
      <option>Fahrenheit</option>
      <option>Celcius</option>
   </select>
</div> 

<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="index.html" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"> Save Settings</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use `local storage` for this:

```
   localStorage.setItem('showInTheNextPage', $('.form-group').html());
```

Then, in the next page:

```
   var fromPrevPage = localStorage.getItem('showInTheNextPage');
   $('.form-group').html(fromPrevPage);
```

UPDATE : Illustration

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16264547/1845408

Page 1: http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/dfqsK/

Page 2: http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ayvPq/

Comment: +1 for a good idea! But please note that `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` does not work in apple devices like iPad, iPhone etc!! :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao did not know that, a huge limitation!

Comment: Yep!! I have struggled a lot in one of my project and not even knowing unless I found some article on that!! :(

Comment: @GuruprasadRao they discussed several solutions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555347/html5-localstorage-error-with-safari-quota-exceeded-err-dom-exception-22-an

Comment: @erkaner.. So basically that answer is to check whether apple device or say safari browser supports localStorage or not right? But the crazy thing was it was supporting in Desktop safari browser but not in devices!! :)

Comment: trying it as we speak!

Comment: where do i put the local storage code in mine? and how do i out put it on a test page

Comment: @bigdowg I added resources that shows how to do it with more details

Comment: it wont work for me nothing shows up on second page nd i copied it line for line in jfiddle =/

Answer (score 0):

may be you  do not need to pass to the "next" page?  may be you need to reload rest (or some part of the page in background), namely use ajax?

```
{your form html here}
<a href="index.html" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="reload"> Save Settings</a>
<div id="content"></div>
<script >
  function reload(evt) {
    var body = $('form#some-form').serializeArray();
    var xhr = $.post(window.location.origin+'/api'+window.location.pathname, body )
      .done(function(data) {
        console.log( "success" );
        $('#content').html(data);
      })
      .fail(function() {
        console.log( "error" );
    });
  }
</script>
```

assuming use of JQuery.