# how to pass javascript variable from one js to another js without jquery?

Tags: javascript, json

I am beginner in web development. I am trying to send variable from one js file to another js file .
I researched alot before posting this question. I couldn't find any particular method by which i can do this.

My script which defines variable is

```
function getEventData(){
var eventList = document.getElementsByName("events");
var k=0;
var url = "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?categories=";
for(var i=0;i<eventList.length;i++){
    if(k>=3)
        break;
    if(eventList[i].checked){
        if(k==2)
            url+=eventList[i].value+"";
        else
            url+=eventList[i].value+",";
        k++;
    }
}
url+="&token=************";   
}
```

The url variable is perfect. I want to use it in another script which is

```
var jsonData=getJSON('url').then(function(data)
{
 var sjd="";
for(var i=0; i<data.events.length; i++)
 {
     var url = data.events[i].name.url;
    sjd +='<h4>'+ "<br/>"+ data.events[i].name.text + '<br>'+'</h4>';
 }
 document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = sjd ;
 }
 );
```

As seen i want to use the url variable from first js to second which is used in getJSON function.

I found local storage and cookies as a possible way. But storage doesnt work even if i use the link stated in comment. I cant find any good resource where i can learn cookies. Also is there any other way possible?

Comment: Do you want to use the variable on the same page, but in a script loaded from a different file ?

Comment: No. 2 different html pages uses 2 diff scripts @RainerPlumer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing a variable between multiple html pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264253/sharing-a-variable-between-multiple-html-pages)

Comment: No it doesn't work somehow@Yatrix

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, use localStorage to store do the job.

```
localStorage.setItem("myvar", "jour json serialised string of variable");
```

and on the other page use it

```
var myvar = localStorage.getItem("myvar");
```

Again, deserialise on the other page. JSON.stringify is something you should know already. Also jquery has jStore plugin for this.

Comment: i tried this. But when i alert(myvar); in second js it shows null value