# How to change a css class of a page element if you come from a specific web or link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I've implemented a "Tab" functionality inside one of my pages. Following is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  })
})
```

```css
.tab.current {
  color: red;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab current" data-tab="tab-1">Overview</li>
  <li class="tab" data-tab="tab-2">Get started</li>
</ul>

<article id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">TAB 1</article>
<article id="tab-2" class="tab-content">TAB 2</article>
```

It works perfect, but only in this page. What I want to achieve is to have  links from another page (*index.html*) to this one (*features.html*) with a specific tab selected.

Is there any simple way to update my function to achieve this behavior?

[Here is a codepen link with the code.](https://codepen.io/qwervo/pen/OpRXqj)

Comment: i think you can use the tab id as a # in the url and that will mean when you get to that page, the correct tab should load (if you are using [jQuery tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)).  If not then you will need to write your own function to read any # out of the url and select the tab based on it

Comment: You can use `queryParameters` or `cookies` or `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to pass value from one page to another. Then on second page, read this value and process accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing a variable between multiple html pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264253/sharing-a-variable-between-multiple-html-pages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Variable usage on page reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload)

Comment: You can set a cookie or store local data to tell what the last page on your site was...  i think rajesh is on the right track with session storage...  you wouldnt nees to wirry about coming from off site then

Answer (score 0):

Example li `Get started` is `feature.html` and list `Overview` is `index.html`. What you can do is put the class `current` on list data-tab and article id `tab-2` in `feature.html` anyways it will remove the class when you click the list `overview`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  })
});
```

```css
.tab.current {
  color: red;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab" data-tab="tab-1">Overview</li>
  <li class="tab current" data-tab="tab-2">Get started</li>
</ul>

<article id="tab-1" class="tab-content">TAB 1</article>
<article id="tab-2" class="tab-content current">TAB 2</article>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, but this does not solve my problem, as I need to be able to link **both tabs** from external pages. I have a link at the main navbar to navigate to feature.html, wich should show the "Overview" tab . Besides, I have another link at the featured section of the homepage, wich navigates to features.html too, but should show the "Get started" tab.